# How to validate for save but not for delete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

Here is a snippet of my form

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return verify()">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

As you can see I am verifying with a function called `verify()`. I only want to verify if they click "save", I do not want to verify for "delete".

How can I do this? Is there a way I can tell which one they clicked inside the funciton and just return `true` if they clicked "delete"?

Comment: The answer for this question that you already picked is the one you probably want to use, but I think you can send the event to the function with `verify(e)` and then something like `e.value` would likely get you the info you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place `return verify();` in the `onclick` of the button.

Comment: And remove it from the `onSubmit`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a global var.

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return verify()">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete" onclick="window.action='delete'"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" onclick="window.action='save'" />
</form>
```

**JS**

```
var action = '';
function verify() {
    if (action == "save") {
        // validates
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for giving me a solution exactly like the one I asked for. However I believe I will accept Iznogoods answer because it requires less code.